# Disable Diffie-Hellman (DH) key in Ubuntu 16 and Nginx

Tags: ssl, nginx, ssl-certificate, ubuntu-16.04, diffie-hellman

For website hosted in Ubuntu 16 with Nginx, SSL tests always shows B grade. Below  is the reason shown. See also the attached image.  Current SSL cipher settings are below.  I have noticed the same thing in around 8 to 10 servers I have with ubuntu 16 and Nginx.

```
ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.1 TLSv1;
ssl_ciphers 'AES256+EECDH:AES256+EDH::!EECDH+aRSA+RC4:!RC4:!aNULL:!eNULL:!LOW:!3DES:!MD5:!EXP:!PSK:!SRP:!DSS';
ssl_session_cache shared:SSL:10m;
```

> Diffie-Hellman (DH) key exchange parameters. Grade capped to B

[image: Qualys SSL Labs - SSL Server Test]

Answer (score 13):

Finally I found the solution.  By default Linux  uses inbuilt DH provided by openssl. This uses weak key.  The solution is to generate our own.  Use the below to generate new one. I used 2048, you can also try 4096.

> openssl dhparam -out /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem 2048

Then add it to nginx main conf and reload.  Here we go. We now have A grade.

> ssl_dhparam /etc/nginx/ssl/dhparam.pem;

[image]

Reference urls:-

https://michael.lustfield.net/nginx/getting-a-perfect-ssl-labs-score

https://geekflare.com/nginx-webserver-security-hardening-guide/

Answer (score -2):

[The Mozilla SSL Configuration Generator](https://mozilla.github.io/server-side-tls/ssl-config-generator/) is the best way to properly configure your TLS setup.

Comment: Do you think it is because of "ssl_ciphers" used?  I dont think so, I have A grade with the same ciphers in Centos servers.